# Timescaledb Hypertable chunks size

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a missunderstanding about the following sentence from timescaledb about sizing chunks size. The documentation advise as below

> Make sure that you are planning for single chunks from all active hypertables fit into 25% of main memory, rather than 25% per hypertable.

Does it mean that each biggest single chunks of each hyperstable has to fit into 25% of the main memory - that would mean for 12GB RAM that we can grow single chunks up to 3G.

Or it has a relationship with the amount of hypertables and in that case the 25% of the main memory - resulting in 3GB for our 12GB example - is the RAM volume that will store all the biggest single chunks of all hypertable - if I have 100 hypertable I then have to size single chunks about 30MB because 30MB*100=3GB.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Do you really have 100 active hypertables?  For example, does a typical transaction insert one row into each of 100 different tables?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL (and therefore TimescaleDB), tend to perform best when the most recent, more queried data is able to reside in the memory cache. General PostgreSQL server tuning guidance suggests that active data reside in about 25% of the configured server memory. Pay special attention that this includes **all** active tables and hypertables. The chunk size also includes its indexes.

Using your example, then, if you 3GB represents 25% of your configured server memory, and you have 100 active hypertables, then single chunks (on average) would each be sized to 30 MB to meet this guideline.

Be aware, though, that smaller chunks might also negatively impact your query and compression performance, so it's hard to give a 'right' anwer without a deep dive into your specific needs.

References

- https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/hypertables/best-practices/#time-intervals
- https://www.timescale.com/forum/t/choosing-the-right-chunk-time-interval-value-for-timescaledb-hypertables/116

Comment: First, thanks for you answer greenweeds. By active what do we mean? That the hypertable is being queried? I have to admit that I do not understand that active concept. Also I play with the mode adaptive-chunking of timescale to help me understanding better. There is a mode chunk_target_size => 'estimate' which target a size for chunk in place of the time interval - the system calculate it. And that mode set the target size per chunk to almost 3GB for my config with 420 series. Apparently it takes the info from shared_buffers that is 3GB. I have some use case with 7000 series...

Comment: That's a fair question. My interpretation is concurrent queries but maybe that makes little sense here. I'll ask in-house, thanks for the question, bear with me.